# Как реализовать такую же систему ID в адресной строке, как у ВК?

Tags: apache, php, соцсети

Здравствуйте.
Как реализовать такую же систему, как у ВКонтакте? Например, чтобы вместо /?id=564 было /id564 ? Пробовал через .htaccess, и получилось, что он хочет такой каталог. И я не очень понимаю как это вообще сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это примерно реализовано у ВК? Для каждого юзера же не будешь создавать каталог?)

Comment: @ProMaks [http://hashcode.ru/questions/333504/php-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=333792#333792](тыц)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Пробовал через .htaccess, и
> получилось, что он хочет такой
> каталог.

Значит где то была допущена ошибка.

*простейший .htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

В index.php для проверки напишите просто `echo $_GET['id'];` ну а в адресной строке `id245`

А то как вы качественно составите обработчик запросов, зависит уже от вас.

Comment: Преобразования в адресной строке не происходит >_< Из-за чего может быть такое?

Comment: какое преобразование? Если вы вводите sitename.ru/id545, то и получаете в адресной строке это же, а скрипт получает желанный $_GET['id'] с помощью RewriteMod и .htaccess. Учите матчасть короче, инфы в сети полно (ищите что-нибудь вроде "организация ЧПУ на сайте" и тд

Comment: Извините) Что-то завис :) Все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А причём тут MVC к адресу?
Принимайте:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]*)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

На странице index.php ловим $_GET['id'] . Также вместо * (любое количество символов) лучше выставить диапазон {1,10} (чисел может быть от 1 до 10).

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы "реализовать такую же систему" нужно начинать учиться писать веб-приложение посредством MVC, тогда все получится. Если вы передаете таким образом "?id=564" - значит вы пишите еще при помощи функций.

Comment: @Alex_Fender, MVC хоть и де-факто стандарт в веб-разработке, никто не запрещает пользоваться другими паттернами, да хоть и писать без паттернов вообще. Никакой связи между паттерном и парадигмой программирования (функциональная/ооп) нет. Касательно контакта - доходили слухи, что там все как раз-таки на функциональном программировании из-за скорости и того, что default language разработчиков - си.